# Word to PDF conversion fails on machines other than my development PC

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, ms-word

I am testing converting Word documents to PDFs programmatically from Winforms apps.
I wrote the following code which works fine on my machine.
The app consists of a form with 2 buttons and a text box.
Clicking the first button opens a dialog box to allow the user to navigate to a folder.
The folder address is stored in the text box.
Then the second button takes each Word document from the specified folder and creates a PDF with the same name for each.

```
namespace PDFTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                DialogResult result = folder.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder.SelectedPath);
                    txtLocation.Text = folder.SelectedPath.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtLocation.Text = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
                throw new Exception("cDocument: Error atempting to GetPath()" + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            // Get list of Word files in specified directory
            string docPath = txtLocation.Text;
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(docPath);
            FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");

            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;

            foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles)
            {
                // Cast as Object for word Open method
                Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc.Activate();

                object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                // Save document into PDF Format
                doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                    ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
                // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
                // correct Close method.                
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc = null;
            }

            // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
            // the correct Quit method.
            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This works exactly as intended on my development PC, but when I build the solution and distribute to another machine (running the same version of Windows 7, 64 bit) and with Word installed, I get the following error -

[image: Error]

Does anyone have any ideas why my mini PDF app does not work on the alternative machine?

Comment: It looks like you're missing something with the COM reference to Word. Do you have the same version of Word installed on both machines? Are they in the same path on both machines?

Comment: My development PC has a full version of Office 2010, whereas the testing machine has a (starter) version which includes only Word and Excel, but they are both 2010 versions.

Comment: Hmmm. I know the starter editions doesn't have support for add-ins, but I haven't seen anything that explicitly says it doesn't support COM interaction. You may want to try running it on another machine with a different version of Office, or download a trial for the full edition if necessary. It could also be a difference in install locations, but I doubt that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Office 365 free month trial and created a Word document with it.
Then I pointed my application at it's folder and it successfully converted the document to a PDF.
Thanks danielu for putting me up to trying another version of Word.

Looking at this again I now notice that the starter version of Office saves documents with a .doc extension rather than my version of Word which saves it with a .docx extension.  Hence I think the problem was that the following line of code was not replacing the extension correctly -

```
object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
```

All works fine now thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If installing the full version of office is an issue you can still perform the conversion using open office.  Take a look at the following article:

[How to convert office documents to PDF using open office](http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/)